# asp.net best way to clean up unmanaged resources

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, memory-management, idisposable

I am a little confused about memory clean up in an ASP.NET application. I had defined several destructors--I know this isn't the new .NET way of doing things, but I am a creature of habit and I always did it this way in c++-- that were working wonderfully in just about every scenario. However, I have noticed that they are sometimes not called in my ASP.NET applications.

I am thinking about implementing IDisposable, but I am under the impression that IDisposable is for other users of your code, and I am not sure that ASP.NET would call Dispose when it is finished with the object. Could someone clarify on this?

What is the best, and by best I mean that it will always work-- way to clean up my unmanaged memory?

**Edit**

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx) seems to indicate that if the class containing potential unmanaged memory is a member of an encapsulating class, then the destructor is the best strategy. This certainly makes sense to me since I could hardly put a try or a using around a class member. Even then however, that brings me back to my question, it sometimes never gets called in my ASP.NET app.

Comment: Read this maybe it will shed some light.. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About

Comment: Are you sure your ASP.NET app is handling _unmanaged_ resources? It shouldn't, see SafeHandle.

Comment: Try to post a short code snippet concerning your resource management.

Comment: @Henk, I am certain it is seeing as how I have about 1000 lines of pinvoke on an old c api--of which I have to clean up when I am finished with it.

Comment: Then do implement IDisposable and use those objects in `using(){}` blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All classes which handle *unmanaged* resources should implement the [IDisposable interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx).

For a little more info, there are two issues with the garbage collector.  First, you have no idea when it's going to run.  Second, it has zero knowledge of *unmanaged* resources.. That's why they are called unmanaged.

Therefore it's up to the calling code to properly `dispose` of objects that utilize unmanaged resources.  The best way to do this is to implement the above interface and either wrap the object in a [using  ( ) { }](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)  statement or, at the least, a try .. finally.  I generally prefer the using statement.

Also, by implementing IDisposable you are signaling to other developers that this class deals with unmanaged resources so they can take the appropriate steps to ensure things are called correctly.

Comment: Chris, the problem is, the object is a plugin component that has to conform to a certain interface. 2nd, the object was designed to be held in memory for the lifetime of the application. 3rd, the c api has a init and cleanup function that is only supposed to be called when you are absolutely finished using it. I.E. You can't have ten objects in memory and call cleanup on one of them as it will completely deallocate all of the memory used by the api.

Comment: To accommodate this, I have a static hash table storing all instances from the api inside the object. Then I ref count the object. When the ref count reaches 0, I cleanup. To do this, I need my destructors to get called.

Comment: What if the object is a data member of a class?

Comment: @JonathanHenson: I would say that your controller class needs to be the one to implement IDisposable, and would be responsible for maintaining the ref count.

Comment: thanks. I can't say that when it gets down to doing lower-level stuff that I care for all of this garbage collection business. Anyhow, it is what it is.

Answer (score 1):

When working with managed resources, you don't need to implement `IDisposable` or a destructor. All you have to do for "cleanup" is set all top-level ("rooted") references to null (statics are normally considered to be top-level), and the garbage collector will take care of the rest.

Destructors as such are primarily useful with unmanaged resources in cases where callers either forget to call Dispose, or where such a call isn't possible. However, the runtime doesn't guarantee that destructors will ever be called; only that they will be called before the memory associated with the object is finally freed. You don't have to implement `IDisposable`; it's just a convention. It's perfectly reasonable to have a Close() or Cleanup() method that releases unmanaged resources.

Comment: True that it's not *necessary*, but conventions are a good thing.  We often don't develop in a vacuum so by implementing IDisposable you are signaling future devs that this does indeed handle unmanaged resources.

Comment: @Chris It is true that I cannot expect the callers of the code to call Dispose, and it isn't really possible for it to be used in a using block. However, If I am going to have a Close or Cleanup method then I might as well implement IDisposable. The problem is that I want the stuff cleaned up automatically when it goes out of scope or its last reference is released.